# filter:notarray Expected array but received: 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/graphs", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Collection<Graph> getSkeletonGraph()
    {
        log.debug("REST request to get current graphs");
        return graphService.getSkeletonGraphs();
    }
```

Angular call

```
    $scope.graphs = [];
    Graph.getGraphs().$promise.then(function(result)
    {
        $scope.graphs = result;
    });



    angular.module('sampleApplicationApp').factory('Graph', function($resource)
     {
      return {
        getGraphs: function() {
           return    $resource('api/graphs/:id').query();
      }
     };
    })
```

I am not sure why using the filter i get the exception.

looked also in angular doc https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray
My result is array but not sure why I am getting such exception.

Sample result from backend i am getting.

```
[{"id":"135520b0-9e4b-11e5-a67e-5668957d0149","area":"Bingo","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"0db925e0-9e53-11e5-a67e-5668957d0149","area":"jin","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"7a717330-9788-11e5-b259-5668957d0149","area":"Product","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"402d4c30-980f-11e5-a2a3-5668957d0149","area":"fgfgfg","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"404b77b0-9e53-11e5-a67e-5668957d0149","area":"olah","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"cd071b10-9e52-11e5-a67e-5668957d0149","area":"lolo","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"d9808e60-9710-11e5-b112-5668957d0149","area":"catalog","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"2aaca9f0-97e2-11e5-91cd-5668957d0149","area":"btg","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"955e9ed0-978c-11e5-93fd-5668957d0149","area":"promotions","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"1e441d60-980f-11e5-a2a3-5668957d0149","area":"hjuhh","models":[],"enumerateds":[]},{"id":"fb96dfe0-978d-11e5-93fd-5668957d0149","area":"voucher","models":[],"enumerateds":[]}]
```

html

```
<li ng-repeat="g in graphs track by $index | filter:searchText"></li>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are using `track by $index` before you are applying your filter. To resolve this, change your expression to:

```
<li ng-repeat="g in graphs | filter:searchText track by $index"></li>
```

The `track by` expression should always be at the last, after all your filters. Its a rule mentioned in the docs: [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

**Explanation:**

When you don't use `track by $index` in `ngRepeat`, the input for all the filters used is the array, that is, if its

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter1 | filter2",
```

then `items` is the input passed to the filters by default and the filtering is done on this input.

However, when you use `track by $index`, the input to the filters becomes `$index` instead of `items` and therefore the error:

> Expected array(read: items) but received 0(read: $index).

Therefore, to counter this, the array is first passed through all the filters and the filtered result is used with `track by $index`.

Hope this clears it up.

Comment: could you please describe the logic behind your suggestion

Comment: Its a rule mentioned in the docs. Filters should be applied before the track by expression. See in docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: After spending 2 hours trying to figure out why the filter on the Angular website was working and mine wasn't this was the only answer which solved my problem! Needless to say I would probably need to open and read again the docs. However that's very anti-intuitive and the error doesn't help at all, why `track by $index` should be always the last expression? Makes no sense in my head.

Comment: There is a reason for that. When you don't use `track by $index`, the input for all the filters is the array, that is, if its `item in items`, items is the input passed to the filters. However, when you use `track by $index`, the input to the filters becomes `$index` instead of `items` and therefore the error: Expected  array(`items`) but received 0(`$index`). Hope this clears it up.

Comment: brilliant, spent more than an hour

Comment: This should really be displayed much more prominently in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

You should always use `track by` at the end of expression

```
<li ng-repeat="g in graphs | filter:searchText track by $index"></li>
```

Since while evaluating an expression for `ng-repeat` angular needs the final result for track by to work. If you provide it at the end, your filter will be applied and `track by` is computed on final output. You can see the source code at angular docs.

According to the documentation of `ng-repeat`

> If you are working with objects that have an identifier property, you
>   should track by the identifier instead of the whole object. Should you
>   reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM
>   elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript
>   objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For
>   large collections, this signifincantly improves rendering performance.
>   If you don't have a unique identifier, track by $index can also
>   provide a performance boost.